# Remove data from DataGrid without removing binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid bound to a class. My requirement is to delete all the rows of the datagrid without removing the binding with the class.

In a nutshell I just want to reset my datagrid to its original state.

```
        trialCollection = new ObservableCollection<trialClass>();
        trialCollection.Add(new trialClass());
        trialGrid.DataContext = trialCollection;
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Where are your problems in doing so?

Comment: i have already tried certain ways. but binding is being removed. It's like that I want to reset my datagrid.

Comment: post your collection code, post your binding code

Comment: How do you want reset your datagrid? If you're setting the collection to null, then it's normal that you lose the bindings. You can clear it. If you did the rest right, it would show the behaviour you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Remove them from the binding source (the rows from it, not the binding). If your `BindingMode` is set to `TwoWay` then it should work.

You say your DataGrid is bounded to a class and you want to reset it's content but not the binding, then, go to your class, if it's a collection apply the `Clear()` method -otherwise, clear it manually-. Now, once you do that, your DataGrid will be updated to the same binding but that now is empty so it'll become an empty DataGrid, as you want.

Comment: can you be specific? i just want to reset my datagrid.

Comment: it is a collection. said it mistakenly

Answer (score 0):

Do you use DataBindings property or DataSource property to bind your datagridview to the data source?

If you are using DataBindings property, then try this:

this.dataGridView2.DataBindings.Clear();

Or

this.dataGridView2.DataBindings.Remove(dataBind);

If you are using DataSource property, set DataGridView.DataSource to null seems fine. Since you tried this but got errors when
you add new row programatically, could you please provide some sample code?

Comment: For more help
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/780deb53-70cb-4a4c-bdf9-b97e704bdc66